# Running the data (NLSY)

Tags: r

I want to do an analysis on the data (NLSY), a study of the times to weaning breast-fed newborns.

Here is the data, in the table:
[image]

I have installed the following  packages:

```
library(NlsyLinks)
library(devtools)
```

Then tried to run the data:

```
data(NLSY)
NLSY
```

This is what I got!
In data(NLSY) : data set ‘NLSY’ not found

Is data (NLSY) exist? or there is something wrong?

Comment: Are you following a guide or something? I don't see anywhere it's documented that the `NlsyLinks` package has a data set named `NLSY`. It seems to have one called `Links79Pair`. The `heplots` package has a dataset named `NLSY` and the `logistic4p` package has one called `nlsy`. Perhaps you could be more clear what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: The dateset I'm looking for is in the table (see the edit). Is it the same as Links79Pair or NLSY, from the packages you mentioned?